# How to get node inside a node

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Let's suppose I have a variable called `myNode`:

```js
myNode = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0];
```

Here is what `myNode.outerHTML` looks like:

```html
<li>
  <div class="_4ofi">
    <div class="_4ofp">
      <div class="_4ofr">
        <div class="_2hq-">
          <i class="img sp_RGPCxTkOR8i_1_5x sx_20baa4" alt=""></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="_4ofr">
        <div>My div</div>
        <div class="_9079">My caption</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="_4ofr">
      <div aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false"
           class="_kx6 _kxa _4ofs" role="checkbox" tabindex="0">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

I need to access the div that starts with `<div aria-checked="false">` but as this div has no ID. I suppose I need to iterate through the `myNode` elements to find it and click on it.

So I tried this:

```js
for (var i=0;i<myNode.length;i++) { console.log(myNode[i]); };
```

Somehow `myNode.length` returns `undefined`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), you can select an element by an attribute.

```js
document.querySelector('li div[aria-disabled="false"]')
```

If the classes are not going to change, you can increase the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of the selector. If `myNode` is a list of `li` (list items), then you can query from that node at the desired index.

```js
myNode[i].querySelector('._4ofi ._4ofr div[aria-disabled="false"]')
```

---

Additionally, you could iterate over the result set to increase readability.

```js
myNodes.forEach(node => myNode.querySelector('div[aria-disabled="false"]'));
```

Where `myNodes` is a collection of `li` elements.

Comment: Yes but when i already have the myNode variable, how can i search inside it and not in all document ?

Comment: @delphirules You can start [querying](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) from any Element in the document.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you cannot modify the DOM. Otherwise just set an id to the element you want to access and get it by using

```
document.getElementById('myId')
```

If you cannot touch the DOM:

- `myNode.length` returns `undefined` because the returning value is not an array. It is an object. You access its child nodes by calling

  myNode.childNodes
- For the specific node that has the "aria-check". You can access directly with:

  ```
   document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1]
  ```

Not sure why someone would like to access a node in that way, but there you go.

Comment: Thanks, this is close but in this case i now what the childNodes would be. If i don't know, how can i iterate inside all children inside myNode ?

Comment: @delphirules you can iterate through the value returned by `childNodes`. It is a `NodeList`, so just like an array, you can iterate through it, and request its size with `.length`

Answer (score 0):

```
var myNode = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i=0;i<myNode.length;i++) {
  console.log(myNode[i].querySelector('._4ofr div[aria-disabled="false"]'));
};
```

try this it will give you `aria-checked="false"` div content, fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/designerPrasanna/j2dcf0sp/)